# How to Implement Authorization in Laravel with Database-Defined Permissions and Centralized Authorization Control?

Tags: laravel, authorization

Laravel community. I'm looking to perform authorization operations within a Laravel application. However, I want to dynamically determine these permissions from a database. Additionally, I'd like to centralize the authorization control rather than scattering it throughout the code.

Here are the approaches I've tried so far:

1. I've explored Laravel's default authorization mechanisms, but I'm struggling to understand how to integrate permissions defined in the database.
2. I'm attempting to use Laravel's tools to define permissions and roles, but conducting authorization checks throughout the code seems to increase code complexity.

What kind of authorization management structure and coding pattern can I use to fetch my permissions from the database and conduct authorization checks in a single centralized location? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the authentication you can use laravel starter kit , the breeze is the best choice for authentication. by using laravel breeze you can also implement multiple authentication , like admin and user, but you need to make some modification.

Coming to authorization you can use

1. laravel spatie roles and permissions it is the best for making roles and permissions.
2. if you dont want use third party package you can implement it manually you can use laravel's default gates and policies -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3B0sCRCHOo